# Optimizing SQL Server Table Valued function with Full Text Search tables

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, query-optimization, full-text-indexing

I have been trying to analyse and optimize a runtime spike in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014.

**Background of the DB objects**

I found that the stored procedure shows a spike in runtime when there are more number of records in a source table to process.

The stored procedure part that is lagging is a `SELECT INTO` temp table (say *#tempTable2*) statement, that joins another temp table (say `#tempTable1`) and a multi-statement table valued function (say `testFunction`)

Code format below :

```
SELECT t.col1, f.col2
INTO #tempTable2
FROM #tempTable1 t
OUTER APPLY testFunction(t.id) f
```

This function returns results very quick when I tries to test passing a single value like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testFunction(100)
```

But when the actual stored procedure statement runs, it is kind of stuck in the function for hours (e.g: if `#tempTable1` has 12K records, taking 9 hours for the above statement to complete)

This function calls different other multi-statement table valued functions from it.

Also it queries from a table (say `table1`) which has full-text search enabled - uses full-text search functions such as `CONTAINS` and `CONTAINSTABLE`.

The table currently has 6 million records.

The full text index on the table has change tracking set to OFF &
Full text index is configured for 3 text columns in the table.
Also, The table has a clustered index on Id (int datatype) column.

This table is truncated and loaded daily and then below statement executes

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON indx_table1 START FULL POPULATION
```

There is no other maintenance seems to be done for the Full text index table.

Checking `sys.fulltext_index_fragments` returns only 1 record with below details

| status | data_size | row_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 465517531 | 1408231 |

max full-text crawl range for DB has value 4.

--

I doubt the bad performance of the query is due to the unmaintained Full text search function - but do not have any proof for it.

If anyone has some idea about this, can you please share your thoughts.

**Edit:**
Inserted script for TVF(testFunction) and function called from it(fnt_testfunction3) in
https://www.codepile.net/pile/6BDJNPA0

The table with full text search used in testFunction is tbl_FullTextSearch

Comment: FYI: We can't suggest how to optimise the TVF is you don't include the DDL of said TVF. I *assume* it's an iTVF and not an mlTVF at least?

Comment: @Larnu This is a multi-statement TVF calling other MS-TVFs and topping it off with Full-Text. "Hopeless cause" comes to mind, it's probably easier to start from scratch.

Comment: A multi-statement TVF which is called in a correlated fashion (using `APPLY` for example) will be normally called *per row* of the outer set, so it's no wonder you are seeing issues. Without the code for that TVF (and any functions that it calls) we cannot help. We also need the table and indexes, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface where are you finding out it's an mlTVF out of interest?

Comment: @Larnu OP says so *"and a multi-statement table valued function (say testFunction)"* and later *"This function calls different other multi-statement table valued functions from it."*

Comment: I completely missed that @Charlieface . /facepalm DDL is certainly needed then; we can at least (hopefully) demonstrate how to turn the mlTVF into an iTVF.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. added the function DDL in https://www.codepile.net/pile/6BDJNPA0